# Proper Implementation of IQueryable as a Member Variable on a Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to the world of .Net, ASP, Entity Framework, and Linq, so bear with me...

I originally had a model set up like the following;

```
public class Pad
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PadId { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mate> Mates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

(A pad is a chat room - it contains many Mates and many thousands of Messages)
In a Web API controller, I have a function designed to get the 25 most recent messages from the specified Pad.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetMessages(string id)
{
    var padGuid = new Guid(id);

    // Try to find the pad referenced by the passed ID
    var pads = (from p in db.Pads
                where p.PadId == padGuid
                select p);
    if (pads.Count() <= 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var pad = pads.First();

    // Grab the last 25 messages in this pad. 
    // PERFORMANCE PROBLEM
    var messages = pad.Messages.OrderBy(c => c.SendTime).Skip(Math.Max(0, pad.Messages.Count() - 25));
    var messagesmodel = from m in messages
            select m.toViewModel();
    return Ok(messagesmodel);
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that it seems as though **EF is loading the entire set of messages (multiple thousands) into memory** before getting the count, ordering, etc. Resulting in a massive performance penalty in Pads with a ton of messages.

My first thought was to convert the `Pad.Messages` member type to an `IQueryable` instead of an `ICollection` - this should defer the Linq queries to SQL, or so I thought. Upon doing this, however, functions like `pad.Messages.Count()` above complain - turns out that `pad.Messages` is a null value! And it breaks in other places, such as adding new `Messages` to the `Pad.Messages` value.

What is the proper implementation of something like this? In other places, I've seen the recommended solution is constructing a second query against the context such as `select Messages where PadId = n`, but this hardly seems intuitive when I can have a Messages member value to work with.

Thank you!

Comment: You understand correctly. That is EF's behave in this case.

Comment: Not so @TMcKeown you can use LINQ in ways that avoids the problem that is being encountered here. See my answer.

Comment: Why don't you order by SendTime descending and take 25 elements? In memory you could always re-order them to be ascending again.

Comment: Hah, that's an extraordinarily good point - I was an idiot and just grabbed the first example I found of "grabbing the last N rows". I'll definitely be changing that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var messages = db.Pads.Where(p => p.PadId == padGuid)
    .SelectMany(pad => p.Messages.OrderBy(c => c.SendTime)
        .Skip(Math.Max(0, pad.Messages.Count() - 25)));
```

Comment: And where do you expect to get `pad` from?

Comment: Fixed the oversight. A little hard without intellisense :)

Comment: Ahh, I see - so instead of using pad.Messages itself and running additional queries on that, I construct another Linq query altogether. Is this typical in practice?

Comment: It's something I do when needed. In most cases you don't need to get this fancy and what you did in your question would be OK.

Comment: One more follow-up - is what you've written above assuming I've changed the type to IQueryable? Or is Linq/EF smart enough to know to do the filtering down at the database level even with an ICollection due to this being a single query? And could I encounter issues in other places if I continue to use an ICollection (for example, adding additional messages)? Thank you!!

Comment: No you do not change the type to IQueryable. Keep it as ICollection<>. EF is smart enough to use the relationships to bring back the appropriate data.

Comment: What I've done EF will translate to a single database hit. It is clever like that. As you have observed, once you start working with an in memory entity (after a call like `First()`), calls to virtual `ICollection` properties will result in lazy loading if not already loaded. That lazy loading of all elements in a collection is what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Be patient with EF. With time you'll get an intuition for what happens in the database vs. what you are doing in memory. Asking a question like this is a helpful first step. You'll be surprised by how much you can get EF to do in the database. And use a DB profiler when in doubt to see how it is querying your database.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! This clears a good bit of confusion up for me. (I'd up-vote if I had the rep :-) )

Comment: Awesome, my first negative Answer :-) Cheers!

Comment: BTW: Here's a mind bender that will grab the Pad and the subset of messages with one set of LINQ statement. I'm not sure if this will result in one or two database hits: `var padAndSubsetOfMessages = db.Pads.Where(p => p.PadId == padGuid).Select(pad => new { Pad = pad, SubsetOfMessages = p.Messages.OrderBy(c => c.SendTime).Skip(Math.Max(0, pad.Messages.Count() - 25)) }).SingleOrDefault()`;

Answer (score -2):

How do you plan to count the number of results in a DB query without actually executing the DB query?

How do you plan to get the first item in the query without actually executing the query?

You cannot do either; both must execute the query.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with how IQueryable works with Linq. I assumed it would return some kind of 'pre-loaded' query that I could use in additional Linq operations.

Comment: @HaydenMcAfee Yes, it does.  What does `Count` return?  What does `First` return?  Are either of those returning `IQueryable` objects?  If yes, then they can defer execution, if no, they cannot.

Comment: My problem in the case of setting `Pad.Messages` to an `IQueryable` seems to be that `pad = pads.First()` is somehow flattening the resulting `Pad` object, so that the `pad.Messages` is a null value, resulting in errors calling `Count` on it. Not sure how to approach that.

Comment: @HaydenMcAfee When you call `First` you're *executing the query* at that moment in time.  If you don't want to be executing a query at that point in time, you shouldn't be calling `First`, you should be using a method that returns an `IQueryable`.  You shouldn't be altering the entity object's type; you're just breaking it by making it an `IQueryable`, which is why it now has no data.

Comment: I see. So really the solution is to execute another query, like what Jeremy has presented.

Comment: @HaydenMcAfee Something along those lines, sure, although his query is not equivalent to what your code does.  That's also assuming you *need* to defer execution.  If you *want* to hit the database and get that one item, then that's fine, just recognize what's happening.

Comment: @Servy, please explain how it is not equivalent.

Comment: This is all fascinating stuff for someone 'graduating' from PHP/MySQL :P Thank you both!

Comment: @JeremyCook Not sure what about that is particularly mind bending.  The code in the question only ever uses the messages, not the outer object (the object is only used to get the messages) so there's no need for it, not that that wouldn't do what you're trying to get it to do.  It wouldn't hit the DB twice, although I'm not sure if the DB is going to be able to translate that query at all; either it can, in one query, or it just can't, and it'll throw an exception.

Comment: Considering that I've used it a number of times it will work so long as I didn't goof the syntax. I suspect EF will do it all in one DB query but I've never actually checked the profiler on that one. Take care @Servy